# How to get drupal webform module submitted value programmatically?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I want to get the Webform submitted value using Webform module API.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you clear up what you mean a bit? A webform submission produces a lot of 'values', which one(s) are you after specifically, at what point in the process do you want to get them, and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: I know there are hooks available like webform_client_form_nid(), webform_client_form_submit(). But if i want to get the previously saved webform complete data which contain some field that i create using drupal interface then can i get those complete set of information using drupal hook @Clive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got these link regarding webform hooks

[Working with the Webform API (version 3.x only)](http://drupal.org/node/886014)

that contain these links

http://drupalcode.org/project/webform.git/blob/HEAD:/webform_hooks.php

http://api.lullabot.com/file/contrib/webform/webform_hooks.php

Comment: By some little searching i found these link that help me to perform webform task programmatically.

Comment: @VikasNaranje; the last 2 links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom coding: Adding advanced validation or submit code](http://drupal.org/node/1291574) - 
Investigate $form_state structure via print_r or dsm (devel module) and find your submitted data in `mywebform_extra_submit_44` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it, the form was just an email address.

```
function mymodule_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission)
{
  $value = array_shift($submission->data);
  $value = array_shift($value['value']);
  //$value is now the first value entered (in the case of multi-entry fields) or only value entered
}
```

Both node and submission are stdClass objects.

(Done in drupal 6)